# Python: Enumeration based on an enumerated list

Tags: python, enumerate

I have several vertexes that compose two triangles.

Vertexes:

```
A = [0.,0.,0.]
B = [2.,4.,0.]
C = [2.,3.,0.]
D = [1.,1.,0.]
vertex_list=[[0.,0.,0.],[2.,4.,0.],[2.,3.,0.],[1.,1.,0.]]
```

Triangles:

```
ABC=[[0.,0.,0.],[2.,4.,0.],[2.,3.,0.]]
ACD=[[0.,0.,0.],[2.,3.,0.],[1.,1.,0.]]
```

Now I need to export this data to a .txt file, to have the following output composed by two different parts:

```
1 0.0 0.0 0.0
2 2.0 4.0 0.0
3 2.0 3.0 0.0
4 1.0 1.0 0.0
end part 1
1 1 2 3
2 1 3 4
end part 2
```

The first part was easy, as I only needed to enumerate each vertex based on the aforementioned list.

```
file=open("test.dat","w")    
for i,list in enumerate(vertex_list,start=1):
        file.write("{} {} {} {}\n".format(i,list[0],list[1],list[2]))
file.close()
```

The problem is with the second part, as I need to enumerate each triangle (first column) and then assign the values previously given in part 1 to each vertex that compose the triangle.

e.g. triangle ABC is composed by vertexes 1, 2 and 3; triangle ACD is composed by vertexes 1,3 and 4, so the output (previously presented) should be:

```
1 1 2 3
2 1 3 4
```

I would appreciate any help you could give me on this.
Thanks so much.

Comment: I don't really understand how your input data looks - it certainly isn't the piece of code from your explanation. So please provide your exact input data.

Comment: save vertices in tuple, add tuple as key in dictionary and index as value, and use that dict to get the result

Comment: How did you create this data?  I'm suspicious, because in a case like this, you would almost always be doing things the other way around:  You would start with the list of triangle, and create the vertex list from that, in which case you know the indicies.

Comment: The input is as shown.
The data regarding the vertexes and the triangles is provided by some user in a specifc user created function. Then I extract both coordinates and triangles from those functions and I get the lists that I mentioned before.

Comment: So we're back to Tim's question: how does this get generated? There is much redundancy between the vertices and the triangles, so you must have had more info at some point. Otherwise, you mean that the input is the pair of variables `ABC` and `ACD`? If that is the case, you should clarify that, because it looks more like two random examples.

Comment: I hear OP saying that the redundancy is due to the calls to "user created function"(s). It is what it is. Output just needs to number the triangles 1, 2, ..., and give the corresponding vertex numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you would do something very similar.

This would get the vertices:

```py
vertex_list=[[0.,0.,0.],[2.,4.,0.],[2.,3.,0.],[1.,1.,0.]]

ABC=[[0.,0.,0.],[2.,4.,0.],[2.,3.,0.]]
ACD=[[0.,0.,0.],[2.,3.,0.],[1.,1.,0.]]

print('solve ABC')
for i in ABC:
    for j,k in enumerate(vertex_list, start=1):
        if i==k:
            print('vertex found at', j)

print('solve ACD')
for i in ACD:
    for j,k in enumerate(vertex_list, start=1):
        if i==k:
            print('vertex found at', j)
```

This is the output:

```
solve ABC
vertex found at 1
vertex found at 2
vertex found at 3
solve ACD
vertex found at 1
vertex found at 3
vertex found at 4
```

or more generally make a list of triagles and solve in the same way like this:

```py
vertex_list=[[0.,0.,0.],[2.,4.,0.],[2.,3.,0.],[1.,1.,0.]]

ABC=[[0.,0.,0.],[2.,4.,0.],[2.,3.,0.]]
ACD=[[0.,0.,0.],[2.,3.,0.],[1.,1.,0.]]

triamgles_list = [ABC, ACD]

for c, t in enumerate(triamgles_list):
    print('solve item', c)
    for i in t:
        for j,k in enumerate(vertex_list, start=1):
            if i==k:
                print('vertex found at', j)
```

which gives this:

```
solve item 0
vertex found at 1
vertex found at 2
vertex found at 3
solve item 1
vertex found at 1
vertex found at 3
vertex found at 4
```

Comment: you are welcome.  there is a lot more that you can do with the above FYI.

Comment: In addition to what you did before, is there any way I can create a list of the output of vertex found as: [[1,2,3],[1,3,4]]? Thx so much for your precious help

Comment: yes,  absolutely.  You would be able to do a list comprehension (and probably do the same in one or two lines of code)...  what I gave above was just a base working example.

Comment: Thank you so much again for your help. Will try via list comprehension.

Comment: if you get stuck,  just post a question as a new thread. welcome to link me into it too if you like.